# Why compiler assuming `json['x'] = int?`?

Tags: dart

```
class Point {
  int x;
  int y;
  Point(this.x, this.y);
  Point.zero()
      : x = 0,
        y = 0;
  Point.fromJson({required Map<String, int> json})
    :x = json['x'], //Error : `The initializer type 'int?' can't be assigned to the field type 'int'`
     y = json['y']; // Error :`The initializer type 'int?' can't be assigned to the field type 'int'`
}
```

As you can see the argument `json` here is `Map<String , int>` so why am getting this error here.When both are non-nullable here ?
Why compiler assuming `json['x'] = int?`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `[]` operator on `Map` returns a nullable by spec:

> `V? operator [](Object? key)`
>
> The value for the given `key`, or `null` if `key` is not in the map.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html

So if you are asking for a `key` that is not in your `Map` you will get a `null` value back and not an exception.

If you are 100% sure `json['x']` will always work and want the application to crash in case this is not the case, you can use `json['x']!`. Alternative, you need to provide default values or other type of handling in case these values is not in the map.